# Synchronizing MS Access database file 

Tags: ms-access, synchronization, vba, database-replication

I am developing a database with about 10 tables in it. Basically it will be used in 2 or 3 distant geographical locations (let's call them A,B and C). The desired work flow will be as follows:
A,B and C should always have the same database. So when A does any changes he should be able to send those changes over to B and C. Emailing the entire mdb file doesnt make sense since its 15+mb in size. So I would like to send the new additional records and changes only to B and C. The changes B and C make should also be reflected to the other repective parties. How can I do this?
I have a few ideas in mind but cont know how to implement it.

solution 'A' - export the data tables only into a xls file and email that. But the importing of the tables into the mdb file could be a bit complex right? and the xls is file will also become bigger and bigger with time.

solution 'B' - try extract just the changes and email only the new parts? (but how to extract just those)

Solution 'C' - find some way of syncing all users onto the same database(storage) location. I was thinking of a front/back end splitting solution by storing the tables in a shared drive in the parent company's server (which is also overseas). But the network connection between locations is very slow, and I dont know how much bandwidth is needed for this.

Any recomendations would be most welcome!

Answer (score 4):

In regard to sources for information on replication, start with my [Jet Replication Wiki](http://dfenton.com/DFA/Replication/).

But I would never recommend Jet replication for your scenario. The only environment where I currently recommend it (and I've been doing replicated apps since 1997 and still have several in production use) is for supporting laptop users who have to work with live data in the field disconnected from any network, and return to the home office and synch direct with the mother ship.

The easiest solutions with an Access application would be hosting the app on Windows Terminal Server/Citrix and the users would run it over a Remote Desktop Connection, or using Sharepoint. The Terminal Server/Citrix solution has no accomodation for disconnected users, but Sharepoint can accomodate offline usage and synch changes when connected. Access 2010 and Sharepoint 2010 provide a host of new features, including better schema design, the equivalent of triggers and greatly improved peformance for large Sharepoint lists, so it's a no-brainer to me that if you choose Sharepoint you'd want to use A2010 and Sharepoint 2010.

While it's possible to do what you want with Jet Replication, it requires a lot of setup on the server and client ends, and is relatively fragile (not in terms of data integrity if you're using indirect replication (as you should), but in terms of network reliability) -- there are too many moving parts and too many failure points.

Windows Terminal Server/Citrix is by far the simplest, with the fewest moving parts and completely centralized administration, and works very well for a relatively small investment.

Sharepoint is more complicated than WTS/Citrix, but is less complex and more centralized than a Jet Replication solution.

If it were me, I'd probably go with WTS/Citrix if there was no need for disconnected usage, but I'd be salivating over trying out A2010/Sharepoint 2010. If there was a need for disconnected usage, then I'd definitely go the Sharepoint route.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use "Jet Replication". See

- MSDN Search for *jro* at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=jro&ac=8
- MSDN Search for *access replication* at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=access%20replication&ac=3

Answer (score 0):

It's been some time since I did it, but the indirect method of replication worked well for me in a similar situation.

It takes something to set up.  The documentation used to be appalling for it, but I found articles written by Michael Kaplan (aka Michka) that walked me through how to do it.

If your final environment is going to be fairly stable, then use Access the whole way.  If not, then I'd urge you to take HansUp's advice and go with SQL Server or SharePoint.

Do note: if you're working in Access 2007 or later, replication is not directly supported, and you'll have to roll-your-own bits and pieces.  If you're using an earlier installation, you'll be fine, but allow time for some head-scratching.

Comment: A2007 still supports Jet replication, but only with MDB format. The menus for it are there when you open an MDB. Given that indirect replication is the only solution that would be a valid solution to the original scenario, that's not even relevant, as indirect really requires code (well, not entirely, but nobody with any sense would force users to choose the synchronizer via the Access UI, particularly given the dangers of them choosing DIRECT by mistake).

Comment: That sounds spot on.  Like I say, it's been a while since I did this.  Short answer: Do-able.  Long answer: needs some work.